# how to make a hole in the solder like here?

Tags: soldering

How can I make this hole in the solder?

[image]

Comment: Suck out the excess with a solder sucker.

Comment: that's not solder

Answer (score 5):

You can't.  The holes aren't in the solder.  The holes are in the metal the wires are soldered to.

Answer (score 2):

If you have excess solder on the tag, there are several solutions, depending on the tools you have to hand.

- Remove the excess with a solder-sucker
- Remove the excess with braid-wick
- Remove the excess by banging the item sharply on a table when the solder is molten, it might fly off
- Make a hole in the solder using something it can't wet, like a pencil lead, a bit of stainless steel wire, or some thin wire which has high temperature insulation like PTFE.